# in C++ can i add a note that a reference variable is no longer valid

Tags: c++, ide

I recently had a bug in my code caused by me resizing a vector and I had a variable that was referencing one of its elements.  I found the bug, but was wondering if there is a way to tell the compiler/IDE to throw an error if a variable is used after a specific point?

Totally stupid example, but shows what I mean:

```
vector<int> a{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
for (auto &value: a) {
    int copy=value;  //totally stupid but makes sense if vector<int> was actually a vector<some big class> and we are only copying one value
    if (value==5) a.resize(a.size()+5);
    ///value may no longer be valid after this point throw error if try to use value
    
    //can do stuff with copy but not value here
}
```

Comment: *in C++ can i add a note that a reference variable is no longer valid* -- There is no standard way to do this.  But let's say there was a way -- you still have to consider that your program has a bug and needs to be fixed.  And let's say you put the check after your code has done some things to make that reference "valid" again.  You now have a false positive.

Comment: Sometimes the compiler can spot this type of behaviour and when it does it will issue a warning (eg returning a reference to an automatic variable).  But in the general case it is not possible to give diagnostics for Undefined Behaviour. See also - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: One way to use this is to use smart pointers (ie `shared_ptr`), but that comes with some cost.  Depending on what you are actually doing, there are solutions to help avoid this.

Comment: You might post a [mre] of the type of thing that got you into trouble.  Then people will be better placed to suggest suitable remedies.  One thing's for sure: your IDE can't help you here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if the IDE through an error saying i used an invalid variable that would make the bug pretty obvious.  As it is I added a note to my code saying the specific variable is no longer valid after that point.  It is unlikely to be an issue in the future but I thought there really should be a way to tell the IDE to check a variable is not used after a specific point.

Comment: @PaulSanders I added an example.

Comment: Be nice to have, but the problem is for something dynamic like a `vector` a static tool is next to worthless. A mistake like this would only be detectable if no matter how the `vector` was used at runtime the program wound up in the same error condition, and that's so rare that compiler developers won't have invested much effort in tracking and reporting on it.

Comment: If you need to change the number of items in a container while iterating it there are ways to do it, but the range-based `for` loop requires that to don't do it.

Comment: The solution to your toy example is it iterate, count the number of occurrences, and then once the loop is over do a single call of `vector.resize(vector.size() + (5 * occurrences))`

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve this is to take your file, change the variables that you want to track for future use, for example, if you want to track a variable called `foo`, rename it to `foo_test` in all its occurrences prior to the point you are interested about and try compiling/building/testing. If you get an error saying that `foo` was not defined, then it is used later. If you do not get such an error, you are no longer using it.

Comment: I could just do a search also.  The point was I new of a situation that could possibly cause someone down the road to create a bug and was wondering if there was a way to document it so it would automatically throw an error.  looks like that is not possible.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse it is possible, because if you know that `foo` might be problematic, then you can implement a validator that takes the teammate's code as an input, automatically makes the changes as described in this answer and compiles the code. If the test is frequently needed and you know what variables you are interested about, then it is possible.

Comment: ok going to the extreme of writing a custom parser that checks the c++ code yes I guess it is possible.  Renaming a variable just moves the possible error to a new name.  if the problem was ```foo``` should not be used after line 50 and we rename to ```foo_test``` then now it is ```foo_test``` that can't be used past line 50 and ```foo``` just does not exist.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse the idea is that you keep that variable name as `foo` in your code, but you create a copy of your code and in the copy (and only in the copy) you change the variable name up to line 50 from `foo` to `foo_test`. Compiling the copy of the code will reveal where the variable is being used afterwards. So the renaming is only for the purpose of the test and it is not applicable on the actual code. This can be made almost fully automatic via simple means such as creating a git branch for the test where only the first 50 lines contain the change and merging the changes into

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse that branch. That would mean that you have a playground where the variable is renamed in the first 50 lines and you just merge the newer changes into that and compile. The other branches would keep `foo` as your variable. If this is still unclear, then let me know and I will create an example for you.